# Cost to replace "wall of glass" with sliding doors?

Tags: windows, glass, sliding-glass-door

I'm considering buying [this house](http://tour.vht.com/433204865/263-cedar-ln-glencoe-il-60022/photos), which is in need of pretty significant renovation.  The one area I can't even ballpark an estimate on replacement cost would be this wall of glass with large sliding glass doors.

What would be a reasonable range of costs to replace these, not using top-of-the line hardware?  I assume thermally broken storefront glass would be appropriate.  Below is an interior and exterior view.  Following these two photos is another fairly expensive looking section without sliding doors.

[image]
[image: Exterior]

I'm also pretty clueless about the cost to replace this other "wall of glass."  Again I'd assume thermally broken storefront?  Is ~$10k for this section right?

[image]

Comment: Cost questions are generally considered off-topic since they are specific to a region and time.  Your best bet is to get in touch with some local manufactures/installers.

Comment: Is this style common in your neighborhood? You could also try asking neighbors.

Comment: @Steve, this style is extremely uncommon in our area.  Maybe one out of 500 houses is this style.  I thought cost questions would be off topic, but I did a quick check and found other cost questions that weren't marked.  Sorry, I can delete afterwards--just desperate for a ballpark range.  I have no idea if this is a $10k job or a $50k one.

Comment: This is impossible to answer for a whole number of reasons...but assuming you're not going to Home Depot for off-the shelf options (as I think you really want to preserve the lines of this house) your'e likely looking at something closer to 50K for custom fabrication and installation.

Comment: BTW, it's a gorgeous house. Looking at the top photo closer, I see handles on the glass already. I think those are large sliding glass doors. You'll need to likely get those custom built if you're replacing them. You'll need to talk to a window/door manufacturer to get some quotes.

Comment: Is the glass disfunctional, or merely you think you should updated it for energy concerns? What you are looking at is effectively a museum-peice house - you could spend $50K on renovation **and** destroy the value of the house in one fell swoop. A modernist house like this would not be particularly efficient even with the latest and fanciest glass. The renovation bill will pay **many** years of operating costs.

Comment: A modernist house with modern materials would be better (and probably less expensively) done starting from an empty lot, or one with a "tear me down and start over" house on it, rather than with an actual 50-80 year old modernist house...

Comment: @Ecnerwal modernist and modern isn’t the same.Acctualy all modernist houses are, like you said 50-80 years old. And if you ask me it wouldn't be "honest" to build modernist house now from scratch with new materials. It would be like building acropolis out of a cast concrete in 21st century. House is beautiful btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called a well-regarded Chicago-area window company and gave them the specifics.  From our discussion, it sounds like replacing the hardware might be a possibility depending upon the manufacturer.

Otherwise, the wall from the top two pictures should be about $8,000 to replace just the lower sliding glass doors and the stationary panels to the left and right.  I didn't get the impression that replacing the upper panels would be terribly costly in comparison if we decided to do those.  It sounds like the fact that there's a structural beam in place (above the doors) helps keep cost down.

Comment: Why the down vote?